# Does not name a type

Tags: c++

Don't know why compiler is giving "'nodes' does not name a type" error.

```
struct node;
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
struct node *nodes[1024];
nodes[1]->data = 1;
nodes[1]->left = NULL;
nodes[1]->right = NULL;
```

Comment: You should probably ask someone why that is.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you don't allocate memory for `nodes[1]` pointer (which should give you undefined behaviour), the code should compile.

Comment: Might be you didn't assign a type to the node pointer?

Comment: also try using malloc function to allocate the memory by (struct node* ) malloc

Comment: Is this inside a function?

Comment: In C++, you don't need to use the `struct` keyword when instantiating variables, for example:  `node * nodes[1024];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I'm assuming you wrote the code exactly as specified:

```
struct node *nodes[1024];
nodes[1]->data = 1;
nodes[1]->left = NULL;
nodes[1]->right = NULL;
```

The reason you are getting compiler errors is because that is not valid C++ code.

But if you move that code into a function it will compile just fine:

```
struct node *nodes[1024];

void AddFunction()
{
  nodes[1]->data = 1;
  nodes[1]->left = NULL;
  nodes[1]->right = NULL;
}
```