# "Does not name a type" error while having been already declared

Tags: c++

I've started this snake console game but I get this error:

> error: `snakeVector` does not name a type

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

///Dimensions of the box
short xDimension = 40;
short yDimension = 15;

///A vector with coordinates of snake's body
vector < pair <short, short> > snakeVector;///This is weird because I have declared this already here

///Co-ordinates of snake's head
pair <short,short> head = make_pair(12,8);

///Initialize snake
snakeVector.push_back(head);//These get me an error
snakeVector.push_back(make_pair(11,8));
snakeVector.push_back(make_pair(10,8));
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is this code outside of a function?

Comment: UnholySheep Yes. It's in `main.cpp` before defining methods and the `main` function

Comment: You cannot call functions (such as `push_back`) at file scope - that's why you get the errors. Just move those lines into `main`

Comment: The error and your counter are not at odds with each other. You are correct that you declared `snakeVector`; if you hadn't the error would have been about an unrecognized identifier. The compiler is correct that `snakeVector` does not name a type; you declared it to be a *variable*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973928/does-not-name-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

I added the lines with the error inside a function and that solved the problem.